# Content type scoping

Tags: content-type

Why can't content types be web application or farm scoped?

What are the issues because Microsoft did not allow this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a content type hub to allow the scope you need. Have a read though these articles:
http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/understanding-content-type-hub-cth-in-sharepoint-2013

This one is not 2013 but it is a useful FAQ:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaks/archive/2011/02/09/content-type-hub-limitations.aspx

Comment: thank you but i am not allowed to go on links in our network

Comment: @CustomizedName soo you can view stackexchange, but cannot visit a link to 'blogs.msdn.com/...'? Your network sounds crazy!

Comment: @John-o very crazy

Comment: @CustomizedName In summary you can create the content types you want to use in a site collection. Once you are happy activate the Content type synchronisation hub site collection feature. Publish the individual content types you want. Specify the Content Type hub in your Managed Metadata service and set it to push down content types. You will need a detailed reference to set this up for the first time though.

Comment: if you have mobile device, then you can check it from there....But interesting question, how can you access the stackexchange web site from you network, just curious?